# PgAdmin get stuck on database connection?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I want to connect to postgres database and just configured the connection, but every time I want to connect `PgAdmin` get stuck with no response..

[image]

Anyone has faced this issue?

**Env:**

```
x64 ubuntu
```

Comment: Please show us your connection settings and check if PostgreSQL is running (on your server)

Comment: This all should be ok, due to the project is written in dJango, and the web page works normally.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you should confirm Login user have permission to access this PgAdmin/PostgresSQL Server.

If not have, you should try to set true permission to user as below command.

1) chmod -> change read/write/execute permission to your server. 
2) chown -> change owner to your server.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: chmod? PostgreSQL isn't using chmod, just SQL (GRANT and REVOKE) and pg_hba.conf for changing permissions.

Comment: Yes it's sure PostgreSQL isn't use chmod and pg_hba.conf for changing permission to access to all client user including network pc. But my mention chmod just want to change to PostgreSQL installation directory for this linux user.